# Empty space in ImageButton

Tags: android

I have a field for the game Tic-Tac-Toe. Each cell is an ImageButton. When clicked, a picture is inserted. But there are some empty space on the Top and Bottom:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ00M.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clpfn.png)

**fragment_game.xml**

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableGame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

And **Fragment_game.java**

```
final ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) V.findViewById(R.id.button5);
btn.setScaleType(ImageButton.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
btn.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.qwe);
    }
});
```

I want the picture to stretch to the size of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_margin="2dp"
```

You use Margin Padding Please remove Margin and Padding then You can Eaisly do Your Job anotherwise cont

Comment: No. It doesn`t help.

Comment: @Farad I want to say You YOu Remove layout margin and set is 0dp